# Handlebars: not able to compile?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am a very new learner of Handlebars and Javascript so my apology in advance. As a way to learn Handlebars, I am trying putting all basic components from online example into one self-contained web page. However it doesn't run well.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/handlebars-v4.0.5.js" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="content-placeholder"></div>

<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Real Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#users}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{username}}</td>
          <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{email}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/users}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<script>
  var source   = $("#some-template").html();
  alert(source);
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var data = { users: [
      {username: "alan", firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson",      email: "alan@test.com" },
      {username: "allison", firstName: "Allison", lastName: "House", email: "allison@test.com" },
      {username: "ryan", firstName: "Ryan", lastName: "Carson", email: "ryan@test.com" }
    ]};
  $("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I am not able to print the source (alert(source) shows "undefined"). Is anything missing? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You haven't closed the `script` tags properly and hence the issue. Take a look at my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you haven't closed your `script` ta at the top where you include `jQuery` and `Handlebars`.

You should close the script tags :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
```

Here is the complete working code

```js
 var source = $("#some-template").html();
 alert(source);
 var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
 var data = {
   users: [{
     username: "alan",
     firstName: "Alan",
     lastName: "Johnson",
     email: "alan@test.com"
   }, {
     username: "allison",
     firstName: "Allison",
     lastName: "House",
     email: "allison@test.com"
   }, {
     username: "ryan",
     firstName: "Ryan",
     lastName: "Carson",
     email: "ryan@test.com"
   }]
 };

 $("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-placeholder"></div>
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Real Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#users}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{username}}</td>
        <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{email}}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/users}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

Comment: My goodness, I thought "/>" is used to close tag in general. Thanks a lot!